# What is the difference between K-means clustering and vector quantization?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, hidden-markov-models

What is the difference between K-means clustering and vector quantization?

They seem to be very similar.

I'm dealing with **Hidden Markov Models** and I need to extract symbols from feature vectors.

In order to extract symbols, do I do vector quantization or k-means clustering?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The way I understand it, K-means is one type of vector quantization.

Comment: Exactly. K-means clustering is one method for performing vector quantization. The centroids found through K-means are (using information theory terminology) the *symbols* or *codewords* for your *codebook*. To decode a vector, assign the vector to the centroid (or codeword) to which it is closest.

Comment: Maybe you should explain why k-means is a type of vector quantization by explaining what vector quantization is.

Answer (score 5):

The K-means algorithms is the specialization of the celebrated "Lloyd I" quantization algorithm to the case of empirical distributions. (cf. Lloyd)

The Lloyd I algorithm is proved to yield a sequence of quantizers with a decreasing quadratic distortion. However, except in the special case of one-dimensional log-concave distributions, it dos not always converge to a quadratic optimal quantizer. (There are local minimums for the quantization error, especially when dealing with empirical distribution i.e. for the clustering problem.)

A method that converges (always) toward an optimal quantizer is the so-called CLVQ algorithms, which also generalizes to the problem of more general L^p quantization. It is a kind of Stochastic Gradient method. (cf. Pagès)

There are also some approaches based on genetic algorithms. (cf. Hamida et al.), and/or classical optimization procedures for the one dimensional case that converge faster (Pagès, Printems).